# React won't render elements in map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render elements from a map function however it does not seem to be working. I have tried to change the return but nothing seems to work.

```
class API extends Component {
  myTop10Artists() {
    Api.getMyTopArtists(function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        console.log(data.items);
        return data.items.map((artist) => {
          console.log("artist name " + artist.name);
          console.log("artist id " + artist.id);
          console.log("artist popularity " + artist.popularity);
          return (
            <div key={artist.id} className="card">
              <div key={artist.id} className="cardContent">
                <h3> {artist.name} </h3>{" "}
              </div>{" "}
            </div>
          );
        });
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return <div className="cardsWrap"> {this.myTop10Artists()} </div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: just return the api call?

Comment: Was about to say the same, or use a state. I would btw move the whole map in the render part or extract it to it's own component, that function on class into render function feels like an anti pattern

Comment: The API call is most likely asynchronous, but the point still remains that `myTop10Artists` does not return anything, so you shouldn't expect it to.

Comment: @ilkerkaran You mean the "Api" at the start of the function? That also does not seem to fix it unfortunately

Comment: @JulianKleine I would move it to the render part but since I intend to have more data I decided it would be a better idea to keep them as separate functions

Comment: @Wishal I tried to show the flaw. It is a comment (not an answer). Also sorry, I don't personally serve ready answers for this kinda questions ;)

Comment: I would encourage you to use state for the data returned from `Api.getMyTopArtists`. Being that it's an async function, it's small wonder nothing gets rendered using your code.

Comment: @Wishal take a look at my answer for the use of a own component, I don't get the argument of more data, therefore the usage of a function

Comment: Don't think in functions in react, get lost with the class components, start using hooks and think in components. The second you display jsx and you find yourself writing it in a function, you should stop and write a dedicated component, if you use functional components with shorthand (so no state involved) the boilerplate gets very little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea of how to do approach this another way with hooks and functional components. Main issue in your code, as mentioned by others already, is the fact that the results are not returned by the callback or set to a state.

```js
const MyTop10Artists = () => {
  const [artists, setArtists] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    Api.getMyTopArtists((err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        setError(err);
        return;
      }
      setArtists(data.items);
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading && "Loading"}
      {error && error}
      {!isLoading && artists.length === 0 && "No artists"}
      {!isLoading &&
        artists.map((artist) => (
          <div key={artist.id} className="card">
            <div key={artist.id} className="cardContent">
              <h3>{artist.name}</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
    </>
  );
};

const API = () => (
  <div className="cardsWrap">
    <MyTop10Artists />
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Store `items` in state and update it with the api response. This will cause your component to rerender.

Also, move your api call to component hook

```
componentDidMount(){
  Api.getMyTopArtists(function (err, data) {
      this.setState({
           items: data.items
       })
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't work, because you are returning your data from a callback, instead you need to store using `this.setState()`the fetched data into your state and then display it.

```
class API extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null,
      error: null
    }
    this.myTop10Artists = this.myTop10Artists.bind(this);
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
    this.myTop10Artists();
  }
  
  myTop10Artists() {
    Api.getMyTopArtists(function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        this.setState({...this.state, error: err});
      } else {
        this.setState({error: null, data})
      }
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    const {error, data} = this.state;
    if(error){
      return <div>Error! Try again</div>
    }
    
    if(!data){
      return <div>Loading..</div>
    }
    
    return (
      <div>
         data.items.map((artist) => (
            <div key={artist.id} className="card">
              <div key={artist.id} className="cardContent">
                <h3> {artist.name} </h3>{" "}
              </div>{" "}
            </div>
        ))
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: That's how you fetch data in react, to implement the state view mental model. You have an initial state, update this state and then display it. plus you might want to try using React Hooks a lot easier

Comment: You should call `super(props)` before you use `this`

Comment: yea super(props) should be at the top, made an edit

Answer (score 0):

1-use map function inside your return

2-use round braces instead of curly braces to surround your arrow function

```
return ({data.items.map((artist) => (
            <div key={artist.id} className="card">
              <div key={artist.id} className="cardContent">
                <h3> {artist.name} </h3>{" "}
              </div>{" "}
            </div>
       ))};
);
```